# Circle drawing out of screen size

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

Can someone explain me how I can set that canvas doesnt draw circle outside the screen?

In screenshot it looks like this - 
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmAkg.png)

As you can see, some of the circles is half outside the screen but I want that all of the circle is inside the screen.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Random random = new Random();
        int minRadius = 50;
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        for (int i=0; i<resultInt; i++) {
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int randX = random.nextInt(w);
            int randY = random.nextInt(h);
            int color = Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawCircle(randX, randY, minRadius, paint);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Without your code? no

Comment: @mac229 Edited, added also code, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subtract your double radius:

```
 int w = this.getWidth() - 2 * minRadius;
 int h = this.getHeight() - 2 * minRadius;
```

And then fix random point:

```
 int randX = random.nextInt(w) + minRadius;
 int randY = random.nextInt(h) + minRadius;
```

Comment: Editing your answer to match mine, so it appears you posted first? I'll have to remember that trick.

Comment: No man. I noticed a mistake. And when I finished editing post, your answer was identical. Your answer can be marked as correct. I dont care

Answer (score 0):

```
int w = this.getWidth() - minRadius * 2;
int h = this.getHeight() - minRadius * 2;
...
int randX = random.nextInt(w) + minRadius;
int randY = random.nextInt(h) + minRadius;
```